# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wikipedia'

Tags: python, module, wikipedia-api

I am trying to make a line of code, that searches Wikipedia for information. Here's my code:

```
import wikipedia
print(wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia"))
```

I have used the same module in the past, with no problem. Now here comes the error. When I run this SIMPLE 2 lines of code, I get: Modulenotfounderror: No module named: "wikipedia"
Yes, I have tried pip install wikipedia, and pip3 install wikipedia and it says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: wikipedia in c:\users\dinoh\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\dinoh\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from wikipedia) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\dinoh\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from wikipedia) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\dinoh\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (1.26.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\dinoh\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\dinoh\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\dinoh\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.0.0->wikipedia) (2.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\dinoh\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->wikipedia) (2.3.1)
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: one reason could be because of multiple python versions if you now have that. it could lead to you having multiple pip paths which means that you maybe already installed wikepedia on python 3.9 but your executing your code in some other python version which doesn't have wikepedia installed

Comment: What exact command are you using to run those two lines of code?  Are you typing `python` on the command line, or using an IDE, or some other way?

Comment: how are you running the script? do you perhaps have `python` and `python3` installed?

Comment: I have the python app installed (IDLE) and I have Visual Studio Code installed, which is what I am using. I am using an IDE called Visual Studio Code.

Comment: What specific version of Python is Visual Studio using?  If you're not sure, you can run this code to find out: `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: Python version 3.10.1

Comment: That's the problem.  pip installed wikipedia for Python 3.9, but Visual Studio is using Python 3.10.

Comment: So do I swap it's version to 3.9? (Edit: Yup, and it worked! Thx for the help!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, so the fix for my own question was that I needed to use the correct version of python. So I just installed a slightly older version of python (3.9) as I was using 3.10 currently, and then swapped the version of python I was using in vscode. Worked like a charm. If you're feeling lazy, you can also download the version you need off of the Microsoft store like I did. :)

[Click here for image cause I don't have embed perms yet lol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGQMT.png)